# Passing an array to a PowerShell script

Tags: arrays, powershell, param

I am trying to pass an array to a PowerShell script, but I always get just one value. I have googled my butt off, but I can't find anything. All I need to do is pass an array to the script. Here is my code:

```
param($Location)
($location).count

Foreach ($loc in $Location)
{

$loc

}
```

Here is my command I am running:

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\PowerShell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted  -File "C:\ParaTestingArray.ps1" -location Sydney,London
```

Here is the output:

> 1 
>   Sydney

For the life of me I can't get it to grab the other value in the array. I have tried using

```
param([string[]]$Location)
```

I have tried:

```
-location "Sydney","London"
-location @(Sydney,London)
-location Sydney London
-location Sydney,London
-location (Sydney,London)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you passing from a PS script to a PS Script?

Comment: The problem is that the script is expecting an array, but when you run powershell.exe -file ... (etc.) the input string @('a','b','c') is not coerced into an array. If you run the script from a PowerShell prompt, the problem will not occur.

Comment: AdqBill - I need the script to be in a schedule task with each task giving a different location. How would you run the scrip then with out using my method?

Comment: AthomSefre - Nope, just want to send an array to a PS script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot reproduce that result:

```
$script = @'
param($Location)
($location).count

Foreach ($loc in $Location)
{

$loc

}
'@

$script | sc test.ps1

.\test.ps1 sydney,london
```

2
sydney
london

Edit:
This works:

```
$args.count

Foreach ($loc in $args)
{

$loc

}
```

Called as:
powershell.exe -file c:\test.ps1 sydney london

Comment: Thanks mjolinor. The way you do it I get the same result as you. What is wrong with the way I am doing it? Can you try it my way and let me know what you get. Thanks agian!!!

Comment: I get the same result you do if I call it that way.  Not sure how you'd do that.

Comment: I think the problem is that there's no way to present an array as a CMD string argument.  You'll need to use a delimited string, and split it.

Comment: $args means "the arguments passed to the script or function." It can be iterated the same as an array.

Comment: This technique does not work when you need to pass in the array using a named parameter, i.e. when both args populate the same parameter. WHat is being shown when iterating over the $args variable is actually iterating over two different arguments. The answer from Fridden is the correct way to pass an array in a sungle argument to a script using powershell.exe.

Answer (score 8):

Use the `-command` switch instead.

Like this:

```
powershell -Command "&{C:\ParaTestingArray.ps1 -Location A,B,C}"
```

From the about_powershell:

For writing a string that runs a Windows PowerShell command, use the format:

```
     "& {<command>}"
```

Where the quotation marks indicate a string and the 
invoke operator (`&`) causes the command to be executed.

Answer (score 0):

The

```
Powershell.exe -Command "&{C:\script.ps1 -ParmArray 1,2,3}"
```

trick worked for me - but it feels unfortunately hacky.  Definitely counter-intuitive after the rest of my powershell experience.